# Any resources for primary schoolers online?

Tags: primary-schooler, school, learning, homeschooling, elearning

I have a 7-year-old and I am afraid the schools are going to be closed soon so I am looking for online resources to use and keep him entertained. Have you got any suggestions for me?

Comment: Info about your location might be helpful. I assume it is an english-speaking country, but spelling (and parts of the curriculum) will be different ;-)

Comment: UK based but also in Italian would be good as we are a bilingual family :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Beast Academy for math: https://beastacademy.com

They have online classes and books. I recommend both. The problems are fun for both children and adults. I especially like the more difficult problems (marked with stars). The math program they offer gives a very solid base. It gradually builds up the difficulty of the problems from easy to hard. Some children really like Beast Academy and are able to study with minimal supervision. YMMV.

You can check out the online program sample here: https://beastacademy.com/online
and the book samples here: https://beastacademy.com/books

The price is reasonable, and works out to be lower than live tutoring (one-on-one or group).

Comment: Thanks, Timur. They have good resources! I have also been recommended: https://www.twinkl.it because they also do resources in other languages and my son is bilingual so it's helpful!

Answer (score 1):

For foreign language learning, I recommend Rosetta Stone: https://www.rosettastone.com/students/

We used their smartphone app. The Spanish language program (the only one we tested) gives a good, solid base. It gradually builds up vocabulary, entire phrases, reading and pronunciation from simple to more advanced. Some children like it, and can study with minimal supervision.

They have a standard free 7-day trial for students. At one point, they offered a few months long free trial, but this was probably a one-off due to the COVID-19 pandemic. The price is reasonable, and lower than live tutoring (one-on-one and group).

I think that any online language program, even a good one such as Rosetta Stone, needs additional extensive components: (a) live conversations (online tutoring), (b) reading (books), (c) listening (podcasts, online radio, YouTube). Overall, Rosetta Stone is a useful base component in language learning.